# Access font of widget that was set using application wide stylesheet

Tags: qt, qt4

I have an issue where I am setting the font for all QLineEdit's in my application by setting the stylesheet on the global qApp object, but the returned QFont object of a newly created QLineEdit does not reflect the font that I have set in the stylesheet. I am attempting to use the QFont to set some QFontMetrics. Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer on my own.

Calling `QWidget::ensurePolished()` updates the widget's QStyle to reflect what has been set in the stylesheet.

Comment: Note though that this call is only needed if you inquire the font before the event loop gets a chance to show the widget.